# how to use select with like condition for search some words with out Priority status

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, search

i create a store procedure that get a Sentence and separate words with % instead of ' '

```
create proc Mysp_SearchIn_Comments
@text nvarchar(max)
as
set @text = REPLACE(@text ,' ', '%')

select text from tblMediaComments
where Text like 
'%'+@text+'%'
```

it good But the problem is when i search something like : 'bad boy'
 , the results is that comments contain **boy after bad** 
 , i need also show comments when **bad after boy**
i need an advance search such as google algorithm !

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you need to use dynamic sql.

```
DECLARE @text NVARCHAR(max) = 'bad after boy'
    ,@sql NVARCHAR(max)

SET @text = '''%' + REPLACE(@text, ' ', '%'' or [Text] like ''%') + '%''';
SET @sql = 'select text from tblMediaComments where [Text] like ' + @text;

EXEC @sql
```

Query will looks like this:

```
select text from tblMediaComments where [Text] like '%bad%' or [Text] like '%after%' or [Text] like '%boy%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need Full Text Search.
It does most of the fancy search functionality for you.

(Source MSDN)

### Comparing LIKE to Full-Text Search

In contrast to full-text search, the LIKE Transact-SQL predicate works on character patterns only. Also, you cannot use the LIKE predicate to query formatted binary data. Furthermore, a LIKE query against a large amount of unstructured text data is much slower than an equivalent full-text query against the same data. A LIKE query against millions of rows of text data can take minutes to return; whereas a full-text query can take only seconds or less against the same data, depending on the number of rows that are returned.

Take a look at this...

[MSDN Full-Text Search](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx)

Comment: thanks from you , but its just a table with maximum 10000 records , i use your solution in future for big data :)